# Axios interceptors stucks sending request

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, axios, rate-limiting

I am trying to prevent rate limits using Axios Interceptors

I created a RequestManager class for this. It has a method to send the request, after sending the request, it parses the Headers and creates a new object in `this.routes`. `this.routes` stores RateLimits information for each route. Before sending a request, the interceptor checks the rate limits for the current route and if this is the last request it waits for the rate limits to be reset using delay and continues sending requests

Well, it doesn't happen the way I want it to. For example, I send 5 requests for one route, for this route, 5 requests are cut in 20 seconds, but my code does not wait 20 seconds to reset the rate limit and sends a request. It doesn't even bother setting the rate limit data in `this.routes`, why?

```
export const delay = promisify(setTimeout);
```

```
    public async interceptRequest(config: AxiosRequestConfig) : Promise<AxiosRequestConfig> {
      console.log("Check the `this.routes` to prevent rate limits")
      if(this.routes.size <= 0) return config;
      const hash = this.hash(this.getMajorId(config.url as Route), config.method as RestMethods);
      const route = this.routes.get(hash);
      console.log(route, hash, this.routes)
      // Prevent global rate limit
      if (this.globalCounter >= 50) {
        return new Promise<AxiosRequestConfig>((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(config), 1000));
      }
      if (route.remaining <= 0) {
        // Calculate time to reset
        const reset = route.remaining - Date.now();
        return new Promise<AxiosRequestConfig>((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(config), reset));
      }
      return config;
    }
```

```
    public async request<R, B = null>(
      route: Route,
      method: RestMethods = RestMethods.Get,
      body: Nullable<B> = null
    ): Promise<AxiosResponse<R>> {
      // @ts-ignore
      const response: AxiosResponse<R> = await this.axios(route, {
        method,
        data: body
      }).catch(() => {});
      const hash = this.hash(route, method);
      this.routes.set(hash, {
        limit: parseInt(response.headers["X-RateLimit-Limit"]),
        reset: parseInt(response.headers["X-RateLimit-Reset"]),
        remaining: parseInt(response.headers["X-RateLimit-Remaining"])
      });
      console.log("Set information about rate limits in `this.routes`");
      this.globalCounter++;
      return response;
    }
```

Output:

```
Check the `this.routes` to prevent rate limits
Check the `this.routes` to prevent rate limits
Check the `this.routes` to prevent rate limits
Check the `this.routes` to prevent rate limits
Check the `this.routes` to prevent rate limits
Check the `this.routes` to prevent rate limits
Check the `this.routes` to prevent rate limits
Check the `this.routes` to prevent rate limits
Check the `this.routes` to prevent rate limits
Check the `this.routes` to prevent rate limits
Set information about rate limits in `this.routes`
```

Logically, it should have print this:

```
Check the `this.routes` to prevent rate limits
Set information about rate limits in `this.routes`
Check the `this.routes` to prevent rate limits
Set information about rate limits in `this.routes`
...
```